# styles.scss is not getting loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular16

In one of my project (Angular version 16) styles.scss is not getting loaded.

We have added styles.scss into angular.json file also along with the path src/styles.scss though it is not getting loaded in chrome browser.

Comment: Is there any error message in the Chrome Debugger? If yes, please post it. Also try to clear browser cache and if you are running it on a server, restart the server.

Comment: have you try to close the terminal and run again? if you added it for the first time you need to reload the file by run the project again with 'ng serve'

Comment: Include your angular.json